# Creating a link to a specific page of another pdf file

Tags: hyperref

I tried to look at answers about package hyperref but I didn't find anything that allows me to add the full file path.
I am using abode acrobat reader.
Does is work with hyperref?
what is the syntax for linking page 7 of pdf file 'Mypdf' with the path 'fullPath'?

Comment: Please tell us more about ‘mypdf.pdf’: Is it any old pdf file, or does it get created by pdflatex? Please also tell us more about the particulars of the desired hyperlink to page 7 of the file: should the link point to something of particular interest on p.7, or should it point to something specific, such as a numbered equation or a numbered theorem?

Comment: it is an  random pdf that was not made by me (are there things I need to check if its blocked? if so what are they?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mypdf.pdf is a local file, page linking may not work as desired. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

An alternative way is to use "Destinations". Open the file Mypdf.pdf in Adobe Acrobat. Go to page 7 and add a "Destination", let's say the name of the destination is "DestinationName". Then the hyperlink will be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \href{Mypdf.pdf#DestinationName}{SomeText}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#page=17}

abc
\end{document}
```